# Cannot Pull branch

Tags: linux, git, git-branch

I am new to git.

I pushed some new changes to an online branch from my laptop. Now in the server(**Linux CentOS**) I want to pull the changes.

I stashed all the files, so when I check this `'git status'`, the output will be:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 35 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

---

When I `git pull origin master`, it gives me:

```
From https:***************** 
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating ddebf93..669051e
error: Untracked working tree file 'framework/.htaccess' would be overwritten by merge. Aborting
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: regardless whether the file is in your `.gitignore` or not, you fetch the upstream branch and the `.htaccess` is checked in **there**. Either remove `.htaccess` from your `.gitignore` or remove the `.htaccess` from your remote repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the files from the repo, by removing the framework folder from the **.gitignore** file.

I think the problem was raised, because in **.gitignore** the newer version I didn't have a line for the framework folder, but the local version of **.gitignore** in the server had that line; so I think that what was causing the issue for git.

Answer (score 4):

The framework/.htaccess file on your server is not part of your git repo.

The stash will only work for files that have already been added to your repo.

Add framework/.htaccess to your repo

```
git add framework/*
```

Or ignore it in a .gitignore file

Then commit and push/pull again

Comment: @Ayman Unfortunately some machine didn't have .htaccess in .gitignore or ignored that, and added a copy on .htacccess.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder .htaccess is part of the framework folder, when I removed the file, it just looped for the next file that wasn't in the repo and crashed again.